# What is the advantage of using BaseAdapter over ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android

What's the purpose of `BaseAdapter`s? When should they be used instead of `ArrayAdapter`s? I see `BaseAdapter` used all the time, but why not use `ArrayAdapter`? `ArrayAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter` and therefore inherits all its methods.

Comment: There is probably not a great answer to this question. People will often work from the most basic class they can, and only work from a more complex class if they need that additional functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It's the **D** in [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), i.e. [Dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

In other words, when designing code one should depend on interfaces and base classes, and not concrete classes. In particular, you should only depend on "the maximum number of features you need" in a class/interface. If you don't need anything more than the BaseAdapter, don't depend on an ArrayAdapter.

If you're planning on creating your own adapter, feel free to extend from ArrayAdapter if that suits your needs. BaseAdapter is just the base interface used by several adapters, so classes that needs an adapter can use that.